# Return string based on int

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there an easier way to return a string based on the value of an int in C# .NET2 that this, please?

```
        if (intRelatedItems == 4)
        {
            _relatedCategoryWidth = "3";
        }
        else if (intRelatedItems == 3)
        {
            _relatedCategoryWidth = "4";
        }
        else if (intRelatedItems == 2)
        {
            _relatedCategoryWidth = "6";
        }
        else if (intRelatedItems == 1)
        {
            _relatedCategoryWidth = "12";
        }
        else
        {
            _relatedCategoryWidth = "0";
        }
```

Comment: [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.71).aspx) statement.

Comment: You can use a switch statement, which will not be *easier*, but look better and result in less annoying code-writing.

Answer (score 7):

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {4, "3"},
    {3, "4"},
    {2, "6"},
    {1, "12"},
};

string defaultValue = "0";

if(dictionary.ContainsKey(intRelatedItems))
    _relatedCategoryWidth = dictionary[intRelatedItems];
else
    _relatedCategoryWidth = defaultValue;
```

or use ternary operator, but I find it less readable:

```
_relatedCategoryWidth = dictionary.ContainsKey(intRelatedItems) ? dictionary[intRelatedItems] : defaultValue;
```

or use `TryGetValue` method, as CodesInChaos kindly suggested:

```
if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(intRelatedItems, out _relatedCategoryWidth))
    _relatedCategoryWidth = defaultValue;
```

Comment: *"which makes it kind of short"* - not only short, but avoids doing the dictionary lookup twice.

Comment: @w0lf yes, surely, totally agree, but with only 4 items in a dictionary I only prefer to worry about readability.

Comment: you are right; it's after all a matter of preference. I personally prefer the `TryGetValue` alternative

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you are only interested in special-casing consecutive small integers you can do this with an array lookup:

```
var values = new[] { "0", "12", "6", "4", "3" };
if (intRelatedItems >= 0 && intRelatedItems < values.Length)
{
    return values[intRelatedItems];
}
else
{
    return "0";
}
```

Otherwise the best option would be to go with a plain old `switch`/`case` and possibly hide it inside a method so that it doesn't clutter up the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional operators:

```
_relatedCategoryWidth =
  intRelatedItems == 4 ? "3" :
  intRelatedItems == 3 ? "4" :
  intRelatedItems == 2 ? "6" :
  intRelatedItems == 1 ? "12" :
  "0";
```

This way of writing it emphasises that everything boils down to an assignment to the `_relatedCategoryWidth` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `int[]` or `Dictionary<int, string>`, depending on your keys.

For example:

```
int[] values = new int[] {100, 20, 10, 5};
return values[intRelatedItems];
```

Obviously that only works when `intRelatedItems` can only take values from 0 to values.Length -1.

If that is not the case you can use a 'Dictionary'. Both solutions can throw exceptions if the key was not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictLookUp = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictLookUp.Add(4, "3");
dictLookUp.Add(3, "4"};
dictLookUp.Add(2, "6"};
dictLookUp.Add(1, "12"};

int defaultVal = 0;

if (dictLookUp.ContainsKey(intRelatedItems))
{
    relatedCategoryWidth  = dictLookUp[intRelatedItems];
}
else
{ 
    intRelatedItems = defaultVal;
}
```